# Showing a function is in $L^2 (\Bbb {R}^2)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, spectral-theory

Let $K\in L^1 (\Bbb {R}, C_0 (\Bbb {R })) $ be given.
$f\in L^1(\Bbb{R},C_0(\Bbb{R}))$ means that $\int_{\Bbb{R}}||f(x)||dx<\infty$.
I will denote by $K(x,y):=(K(x))(y)$.

I want to show that $\int_{\Bbb {R}^2} |K (x-y, y)|^2 dxdy $ is finite.

What do we know:

By definition, $\int_{\Bbb{R}}||K(x)||_{\infty}dx<\infty$.
Thus, for every fixed $y\in \Bbb{R}$, $\int_{\Bbb{R}}|K(x-y,y)|dx<\infty$.

Unfortunately, I do not see how to approach to it. 
I'd just note that this is a part of another question that I have, so I'm not sure that this is even true. 
Any idea (or counterexample) would help!
Thank you.

Comment: What is $L^1 (\Bbb {R}, C_0 (\Bbb {R }))$

Comment: @FrankLu my guess is that it means $x\mapsto K (x,\cdot)$ is a (Bochner) integrable function taking values in the space $C_0$, but it is not entirely clear.

Comment: An integration in a Banach space. $f\in L^1 (\Bbb {R}, C_0(\Bbb {R})) $ means $\int_{\Bbb {R}}||f (x)||dx<\infty $

Comment: For clarity, you may want to add to the question the definition of $C_0$ and $L^1(\mathbb{R},C_0)$.

Comment: Where is the second variable for $K$ coming from?

Comment: Sorry , I edited my question. Hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\iint|K(x-y,y)|^2dxdy=\int\left(\int|K(x-y,y)|^2dx\right)dy=\int\left(\int|K(x,y)|^2dx\right)$ so there is no need to consider $K(x-y,y)$.

The fact that $K(x,\cdot)$ is only $C_0$ should suggest that it's not going to happen. For instance, we could take

$$K(x,y):=\frac{e^{-|x|}}{\log(2+|y|)}.$$

For each $x$ we have $K(x,\cdot)\in C_0(\mathbb R)$ and $\|K(x,\cdot)\|_\infty =e^{-|x|}/\log2$ which is integrable, so $K$ satisfies the given assumptions, and yet

$$\iint_{\mathbb R^2}|K(x,y)|^2\,dxdy=\left(\int_\mathbb R e^{-2|x|}\,dx\right)\left(\int_\mathbb R\log^{-2}(2+|y|)\,dy\right)=+\infty.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I have one more question: Do you think that if I change to $K\in L^1(\Bbb{R},C_c(\Bbb{R}))$, it'd work? (Compactly supported)

Comment: Still no, unfortunately. Fix $\varphi\in C_c(\mathbb R)$ with $0\le\varphi\le1$ and $\varphi(x)=1$ for $|x|\le1$, then define

$$K(x,y):=\begin{cases}
x^{-1/2}\varphi(y),&0<x\le1,\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Then $K$ satisfies your new conditions but $\iint|K(x,y)|^2dxdy\ge\int_0^1x^{-1}dx=+\infty$.